# In NestJs and Vendure application, if I add plugins to vendure-config, it is giving error Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ConfigModule

Tags: node.js, nestjs

In NestJs and Vendure application, if I add plugins to vendure-config, If I add any plugins, it's giving error. I tried to add ElasticSearch Plugin as mentioned [here](https://www.vendure.io/docs/typescript-api/elasticsearch-plugin/) in the official documentation.

I'm getting following error when I run the project:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ConfigModule (ConfigService, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the ConfigModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current ConfigModule?
- If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ConfigModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ConfigModule (ConfigService, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the ConfigModule context.
```

I tried to add ElasticsearchPlugin to `imports: [ElasticsearchPlugin]` in ConfigModule. But still I'm getting the same issue.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in Advance.

This is what I tried to resolve:

1. I followed [this](https://www.vendure.io/docs/typescript-api/elasticsearch-plugin/) to integrate the plugin.
2. Then, after getting the issue, I tried to add `imports: [ElasticsearchPlugin]` in ConfigModule and AppModule.
3. Then, the error is still same, So, I tried to add the `ElasticsearchPlugin` to imports, exports and providers array. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to delete the `node_modules` from plugin root directory itself. Actually you dont need two `node_modules` when your plugin is places as a sub directory inside the Vendure project.

You can read more about the issue is happening [here](https://github.com/vendure-ecommerce/vendure/issues/1977) on Vendure's official repo.